# Reinstalling plasma-pa on OpenSUSE

Tags: software-installation, opensuse, pulseaudio, plasma

I am trying to reinstall plasma-pa on OpenSUSE tumbleweed.  Unfortunately, I cannot find any tumbleweed repos and the only downloadable source I can find are these two:

- https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/plasma-pa/
- https://github.com/KDE/plasma-pa

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to work with the download.

Answer (score 0):

I [found `plasma5-pa`](http://download.opensuse.org/tumbleweed/repo/oss/x86_64/plasma5-pa-5.16.1-1.1.x86_64.rpm) in what Google told me was the official OpenSUSE Tumbleweed repository.

Is that the package you were looking for?

If so, then it should install with:

```
zypper install plasma5-pa
```